Tangent cone of a convex set
I am considering a convex set $C$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a point $\bar{x}\in C$. The tangent cone of $C$ at $\bar{x}$ is defined by the set $T_{C}(\bar{x})$ composed of element $d\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that there exist sequences $(x_n)_n\subset C$ and $(\varepsilon_n)_n$ a sequence of positive real numbers such that $x_n$ converges to $\bar{x}$ and $\varepsilon_n$ converges to $0$ and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n - \bar{x}}{\varepsilon_n} = d
$$
I would like to prove that if $C$ is convex, then $T_{C}(\bar{x})$ is equal to the closure of the set $\{\lambda(x-\bar{x}) : \lambda>0, x\in C\}$
Prove that $T_{C}(\bar{x})$ is included in the closure of $\{\lambda(x-\bar{x}) : \lambda>0, x\in C\}$ is not difficult and do not use the convexity of $C$. However, I encountered some difficulty to prove the other inclusion, my idea was to use the fact that the tangent cone is closed, so it suffices to prove that if $d=\lambda(x-\bar{x})$ for some $\lambda>0$ and $x\in C$, then $d\in T_{C}(\bar{x})$. To go further, we can consider $x_n = x\frac{\lambda}{n} + (1-\frac{\lambda}{n})\bar{x}$ for n large enough to ensure that $\frac{\lambda}{n}<1$ and $\varepsilon_n = \frac{1}{n}$. If $m<n$, just take $x_m = x$ and then we have that $x_n\in C$ for all $n\geq 1$ and clearly for n large enough we always have $\frac{x_n-\bar{x}}{\varepsilon_n}=d$, hence $d\in T_{C}(\bar{x})$ and the conclusion follows easily.
I think it is correct, but I would like to know if you have a nicer way to prove it.
Also, I restricted myself to euclidean space but I think the same procedure applies to any normed space, what about topological vector spaces ? Is this result still true ?
Thank you a lot !

Imho this is the standard proof. This is also the easiest way to prove convexity of $T_C$ for convex $C$. The proof is valid in normed spaces, as it does not use special properties of $\mathbb R^n$.

Note that $C - \{ \bar{x} \} \subset T_C(\bar{x})$. Since $T_C(\bar{x})$ is a closed cone, we have $\text{cl}\ [\mathbb{R}_+ (C - \bar{x})] \subset T_C(\bar{x})$. Conversely, let $d \in T_C(\bar{x})$, then for $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(\epsilon_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ as defined above, the point $\frac{x_n - \bar{x}}{\varepsilon_n}$ is in $\mathbb{R}_{+}(C - \bar{x})$. Consequently, its limit $d$ is in the closure of this latter set.
